# how to integrated activiti in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, activiti, business-process-management

I need to implement business process management in application development in angularjs (via REST). I searched and I found activiti, camunda and bonitaBPM.

Someone have it knowledgment about ? Which is the best?

Comment: "which is best" always leads to a "depends" answer ;^) Anyway,  Activi has a REST   war module which is quite simple to use. If you don't need the additional features provided by Camunda or Bonita, it probably is the simplest solution.

Comment: Thanks for u reply.  Do u know some tutorial about activiti rest bpm in angularjs ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but in this scenario Activiti is just a regular REST service. Just create some service modules and you should be fine. The available resources are well documented in the guide.

Comment: Thanks for u help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go through https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#_rest_api
for built in Activiti rest apis.

You will need an Activiti installation to connect to. 
how ? see this installation video https://youtu.be/Px2O4aUBEEE

Then From Angular you can make Ajax calls to These Rest API's.